# How to show that the coordinate ring of a finite set of points in projective space is Cohen-Macaulay?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay

Could anyone give me a hint how to show this one:

> Let $V$ be a finite set of points in projective space. How to show that the coordinate ring of $V$ is Cohen-Macaulay?

Comment: Hint: For a $k$-dimensional ring, Cohen-Macaulay is equivalent to $S_k$. What is $k$ here, and what does $S_k$ mean explicitly?

Comment: Just to check, when you say coordinate ring, you mean that you have $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ and you are looking at the corresponding homogenous quotient of $\mathbb{C}[x_0, \ldots, x_n]$, right? @Georges Elencwajg's hint assumes that you mean $H^0(X, \mathcal{O})$, which is also a reasonable interpretation, but makes this question very easy, so I don't think it's what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Proof 1**: Regular $\implies$ Cohen-Macaulay.

**Proof 2**:   Artinian  $\implies$ Cohen-Macaulay.